# Navigating through multiple components in the same screen with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobile-development

I have three cards which needs to be shown individually in the same screen. I am currently hiding 2 of them when 1 is shown which depends on the card that I need to show. I set their states(hidden or shown) by a click of a button. The idea is to simulate navigation from the first card component to the third card component with 'go back' and 'next' buttons. On the third card, there will be no 'go back' button but I still need to be able to go back to the second one by the back function of the phone.

Is there a way to implement this using react-navigation?

This is my code:

```
function Screen (){
     const [card1, setCard1] = useState(true)
     const [card2, setCard2] = useState(false)
     const [card3, setCard3] = useState(false)

     const first = () =>{
        setCard1(true)
        setCard2(false)
        setCard3(false)
     }
     const second = () =>{
        setCard1(false
        setCard2(true)
        setCard3(false)
     }
     const third = () =>{
        setCard1(false)
        setCard2(false)
        setCard3(true)
     }

    return(
        <View>
            {card1 && 
            <FirstCard>
               <Button title="Next" onPress={second}/>
            </FirstCard>
            }
            {card2 && 
            <SecondCard>
               <Button title="Cancel" onPress={first}
               <Button title="Next" onPress={second}/>
            </SecondCard>
            }
            {card3 && 
            <ThirdCard>
               <Button title="Submit" onPress={console.log("submitted")}/>
            </ThirdCard>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a flatlist in horizontal mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have optimise the logic of implementation and handle `Back` button.

```
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

function Screen() {

  /* 1 for Card1 , 2 for Card2 and 3 for Card3 */
  const [cardType, setCardType] = useState(1);

  const backAction = () => {
    // condition is true when It is showing card 2 or card 3 on back press
    if (cardType > 1) {
      setCardType(cardType - 1);
      return true;
    }
    // let the default thing happen
    return false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
  }, []);

  const first = () => {
    setCardType(1);
  };
  const second = () => {
    setCardType(2);
  };
  const third = () => {
    setCardType(3);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {cardType === 1 && (
        <FirstCard>
          <Button title="Next" onPress={second} />
        </FirstCard>
      )}
      {cardType === 2 && (
        <SecondCard>
          <Button title="Cancel" onPress={first} />
          <Button title="Next" onPress={second} />
        </SecondCard>
      )}
      {cardType === 3 && (
        <ThirdCard>
          <Button title="Submit" onPress={console.log("submitted")} />
        </ThirdCard>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is much better way of doing it without react-navigation though I am still not sure if react-navigation have a much easier way to do this. I used this and it worked but the backhandler eventlistener doesn't seem to work the way it's intended. I think it has something to do with react-navigation because I am already using it for navigating between screens. When I use the back function of the phone, it just goes the previous screen, it doesn't show the previous card.

Comment: @captainalbert It should show the previous card as per the condition. Have you tested, Is it calling back handler when you pressing Android's default back button?